# remove string from list that is containted in a class list

Tags: c#, loops, reference

I have a the below list:

```
List<MyClass> problemList = new List<MyClass>;
```

the class is structured like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public List<string> ForumList { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        ForumList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

I have another list that is sent in as a parameter:

```
List<string> fForums = new List<string>;
```

I need to be able to go through my **ProblemList.ForumList** and remove all forum names that are 
**NOT** in the **fForums** List.

The closes I came to getting this to work cause me to get an error in reference to modifying the problemList in the loop. (my code may not work because i have deleted the code but was trying to remember it of the top of my head)

```
foreach (var i in problemList)
    foreach (var n in i.ForumList)
        if (!fForums.Contains(n))
                     i.ForumModList.Remove(n);
```

Does anyone know how to make this work? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think changing my outside loop to a for may work. Will have to try Monday morning, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious route is to create the intersection of both forum lists and assign it to the property:

```
problemList.ForEach(mc => mc.ForumList = mc.ForumList.Intersect(fForums).ToList());
```

For the following example:

```
List<MyClass> problemList = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass {ForumList = new List<string>{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}},
    new MyClass {ForumList = new List<string>{"aaa", "bbb"}},
    new MyClass {ForumList = new List<string>{"xxx", "yyy"}},
};

List<string> fForums = new List<string> {"aaa", "bbb"};

problemList.ForEach(mc => mc.ForumList = mc.ForumList.Intersect(fForums).ToList());
```

The items in the problemList will have the following values for their ForumList:

1: `"aaa","bbb"`

2: `"aaa","bbb"`

3: `<empty>`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to make a new copy of your forumList every iteration. Like this:

```
foreach (var i in problemList)
    List fList = new ArrayList(i.ForumList);
    foreach (var n in fList)
        if (!fForums.Contains(n))
                     i.ForumModList.Remove(n);
```

This way you're not editing the list you iterating but a copy of it.

Comment: Will this make a copy or a reference?. Will have to try Monday morning, when I get back. Thanks for help

Comment: It will create a copy.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to remove from problemList's ForumList all the entries not found.  You could do the following:

```
problemList.ForumList.RemoveAll(f => !fForums.Contains(f));
```

Tested with:

```
MyClass problemList = new MyClass();
problemList.ForumList.Add("A");
problemList.ForumList.Add("B");
problemList.ForumList.Add("C");
problemList.ForumList.Add("D");
problemList.ForumList.Add("E");

List<string> fForums = new List<string>();
fForums.Add("C");
fForums.Add("D");

problemList.ForumList.RemoveAll(f => !fForums.Contains(f));
```

`problemList.ForumList` has two items left, `C` and `D`.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Great!. Will have to try Monday morning when I get back to work. I like your solution because it is compact. Tried to use the .where .select .remove .contains but couldn't figure out right combinations.

Comment: @chris I wasn't sure if I was interpreting the question correctly :)  Hope it works for you.

Comment: It didn't work because I have a list of ptoblemList. Your solution will only work on a single class object.

Comment: @chris you can just `problemList.ForEach` and then do what I did... it's just another layer and so should work just fine.  I think my solution is more efficient as it edits the current list instead of creating a new version and reassigning it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version you want, so I'll leave two versions:

This will remove from each `problemList`'s ForumList which matches an item in fForumn.

```
foreach (var problemItem in problemList)
{
    problemItem.ForumList = problemItem.ForumList
        .Except(fForums);
}
```

---

In this version, you need to look at each `problemList` item. For that item, see if any of the `ForumnList` elements matches an item in `fForums`. If there are any that match, exclude the `problemList` element.

```
var filteredList = problemList
    .Where(x => !x.ForumList.Intersect(fForums).Any())
    .ToList();
```

`Intersect` will return the elements that are in both `x.ForumList` and `fForums`. So if there are `Any` that match, it should be excluded.